# Change DateFomat in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, date, xamarin, xamarin.android, date-format

I am work on Xamarin with Android. And I have use `DatePicker` in my Project.The code is Below.

Code inside the `OnCreate` method.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_register);

            tiebirthdate = FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.tiebirthdate);
            tiebirthdate.Click += DateSelect_OnClick;

       }


void DateSelect_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatePickerFragment frag = DatePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate (DateTime time)
            {

                var dateAndTime = time;

                var tt = dateAndTime.Date;
                tiebirthdate.Text = tt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            });
            frag.Show(FragmentManager, DatePickerFragment.TAG);
        }
```

Create Class.

```
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment,
                                  DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

        // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
        Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

        public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
        {
            DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
            frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;
            return frag;
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                           this,
                                                           currently.Year,
                                                           currently.Month,
                                                           currently.Day);
            return dialog;
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);

            _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);

        }
    }
```

After I trying Finally I set `DateTime` like this format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`. But My server Require Date Format like this `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` . So How to change the `DateTime` format like upper.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tiebirthdate.Text = dateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can try this way.

Comment: @Ironman you are welcome, you can accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method. See the examples in the referenced MSDN page.